# Installation of server does not accept subnet CIDR

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ipv4, subnet

I try to install a server from scratch with a fixed IP address. For installation I use the provided ISO of 18.04.3 and the installation agent of Ubuntu.

First I thought that my understanding of the subnet CIDR was wrong, but after I received credible information from `https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63499/how-to-interpret-subnet-mask` I am sure that this is more a problem within Ubuntu.

When I enter `255.255.252.0/22` as subnet CIDR and `10.16.192.252` as the IP address I get the error message that `10.16.192.251 is not contained in 255.255.252.0/22`. But a subnet calculator tells me that `10.16.192.1 - 10.16.195.254` would be part of the subnet.

[image]

Comment: `subnet` does NOT mean the subnet mask.  It means the network segment your device is on, and its gateway.  So, 10.16.192.0/22 for the Subnet.  NOT the subnet mask (which is defined by the `/22` portion)

Comment: @ThomasWard This worked. Do you want to create an answer ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The prompt wants a **network address with CIDR prefix**.  That is, if you are using `10.16.192.251/22` for your network (255.255.252.0 subnet mask, /22 CIDR mask), you need to first *calculate* the network address (the first IP of the range, usually a .0 with ones like this in the last subnet, but could be a different third octet, in this case 10.16.192.0 is the network address) and then put that in for `subnet` with the CIDR mask.

Therefore, use `10.16.192.0/22` for the Subnet field.  This is used to autocalculate Broadcast address and Gateway address on a 'default' network, but in the case here also makes sure that the Address you enter is in fact in the subnet you're looking to add it to.

Comment: Why can't Ubuntu's installer calculate it itself? All other static IP GUI wizards can handle it themselves.

Comment: http://www.subnet-calculator.com/

Comment: @u15p7fgy863eiq5 Because ask the Server team?  Might be a feature you should request.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a subnet mask in different ways: Separate from the IP address, or in combination with it. You're doing both at the same time ;)

The subnet mask `255.255.252.0` is, written in binary, `11111111.11111111.11110000.00000000`. That basically means, the front 22 bits are fixed for all IP addresses in this subnet, only the last ten bits can vary. So the subnet encompasses IP addresses from `10.16.192.0` to `10.16.195.255`. The first and the last addresses in those range have special purposes, so host systems can have IP addresses from `10.16.192.1` to `10.16.195.254`.

The other way to specify the subnet mask is to just write the number of fixed bits after the IP address, separated by a slash. In this case, the first 22 bits are fixed, so the so-called CIDR notation would be `10.16.192.251/22`.

So you can write the IP address and the subnet as either

> IP address 10.16.192.251 with subnet mask 255.255.252.0

or as

> 10.16.192.251/22

but not both at the same time. And in any case, you don't combine one notation of the subnet mask with another notation of the subnet mask, as you've done in 255.255.252.0/22 ;)

Comment: `255.255.252.0` is rejected by the installer, it insists on a CIDR notation.

Comment: Please try `10.16.192.0/22` in the subnet field. Thank you, @ThomasWard